# How do I wrap an entire third-party library/framework inside a namespace?

Tags: php, wordpress, namespaces, twig

I've written a reasonably well received plugin for WordPress. Several revisions ago, I began including Sensio's Twig in the plugin, in an effort to have a clean separation of concerns for presentation and logic. Recently (well over a year or so since I began including twig), I've been hearing users complain that they can no longer activate the plugin; they get an error stating that "Twig_Autoloader" cannot be redeclared, or something that similarly indicates that there's another instance of Twig in another plugin.

Honestly, I should have thought of that - it was a sad oversight on my part to not consider someone else might be using Twig. I facepalmed on that ;-) Resolving it seems to be trickier than I thought it would be, though. Twig uses an autoloader, PSR-0 compliant, I believe. I can't simply declare a namespace at the head of my plugin and rewrite a few lines to reflect the new namespace, as the autoloader seems to load everything into the global namespace.  This is still true if I declare a namespace for the autoloader class - the Autoloader class will use the new namespace for itself, but everything it loads goes into the global namespace.

I could simply check to see if the autoloader class already exists, and then use the other instance, but I'm not guaranteed the same version will be used, which will lead to odd errors down the road. I could manually go and declare a name space in each file that's in the included Twig library, but that seems inelegant and inefficient.

In other languages, I could simply wrap the whole thing in a new class, but PHP doesn't have that particular nicety.

So - what's the best way to do this??

Thanks So Much!